# Dynamic User ID connection excel connected to Azure Analysis services

Tags: excel, azure, connection-string

I have created an excel report that is connected to the AAS, set to 'refresh data while opening the file'. while sharing the report to a specific set of users, the report does not let the user change the Microsoft login, but keeps taking the user to my ID, unless the User ID is edited in connection string under queries and connections. Is there a way to dynamically change the User ID, according to the user accessing the report?